# Moved rails blog app locally up a directory. Website works but DB content is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm pretty new to Ruby, Rails and development in general. I'm learning quite a bit but I've hit a brick wall with an issue that I know has to have a simple solution. My Rails app is stored locally in "/Blog/Blog/" and I'd like to move it up a directory to just "/Blog/". However, when I move all the files and folders up a directory and run "rails s" and refresh my browser, I'm presented with a "ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError" that recommends that I run "bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development" to fix it. When I run a database migration, the site loads without any errors but it's not loading any of the posts I have stored in the DB. Since this looks to be very much DB related, I did some research and tried "bundle exec rake db:migrate" "rake assets:clean", "rake assets:precompile" and "db:schema:load". All of this clears the error, but none of the blog posts show up.

The saddest part for me is that I figured it was best to wipe everything I have locally in terms of the blog app and then clone it back down from GitHub to try and start over again. The goal being to move it up a directory and sync it back to GitHub so the app becomes the root instead of living in a sub-directory making future deployment more complicated. Now, when I run "rails s" right after cloning it down, I get the same error. When I migrate the DB, the site works but all the DB content is missing just like before. It's confusing to me because before the last push to the GitHub repo, everything was functioning perfectly.

It wouldn't be a huge deal for me if I have to start from scratch in terms of blog posts. But, I'm not excited about figuring out how to fix devise so that it will let me create a new account again and then removing that capability once more. I suppose I could revert back to before that and then sort of redo the tutorial but I'm hoping there is a smarter approach to fix this.

I've spent most of the day googling this issue but I don't think I know enough about whats really going on here to know the right search terms. Anybody have any suggestions as to what might be going here and what I can do to troubleshoot it further?

More info:

This is the blog tutorial that I just finished [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL23ZvcdS3XPK9Y4DRU-BiJtiY5L_QhUUq).

I'm using ruby 2.3.3p222/Rails 5.0.4 with Ubuntu 14.04 on Linux Subsystem for Windows.

Additional Gems I'm using:

- pygments.rb ~> 0.6.0'
- redcarpet ~> 3.2.2'
- friendly_id ~> 5.2', '>= 5.2.1'
- will_paginate ~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.6'
- mail_form ~> 1.7'
- devise ~> 4.3'

Let me know if there is any more info that I need to give.

**My database.yml**

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Comment: What db are you using? If is sqlite, your data is saved in a file located in `db/` folder. Could you please include your `config/database.yml` to your question?

Comment: Yeah, I am using sqlite. I should of included that info before. I appended my question per your request. Let me know if you have any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that .gitignore has a few important lines of code by default.

> Ignore the default SQLite database.

I commented that out and it solved my missing database issue when cloning down from git. I knew it had to be simple... but that's impressively simple.